# Close reason window force closes when user edits question

Tags: support, bug, flags

I've stumbled upon some weird behaviour... and I'm pretty sure it should not occur.

Earlier, I was trying to flag a question because I have suspicions that user belongs to a voting ring.

As I was typing out my reason for raising a custom flag, the user edited their question, and the text box automatically disappeared. Naturally, I had to re-open the flag window (is that what it's called?) and type out my entire reason again. I got ninja'd by that user twice, actually.

I've determined that you either have to be typing into the box, or clicking on it as the post is edited for it to force close. It *could* be the case that my actions on the flag box are interpreted as me wanting to refresh the post to display the edited content.

Not really a *huge* issue, but a bit vexing nonetheless. I haven't checked whether this occurs on answers, but I'm guessing it does.

Can this problem be identified and fixed?

Comment: What about when you are flagging for closure of a question for problems with the content but the question is fixed while you are flagging it? Maybe it should save the text in the custom field but I think that happens to prevent sending close votes that are no longer needed.

Comment: Fool me once... :P

Comment: So voting rings just have edit scripts running to prevent custom flags heh.

Comment: @JoeW I don't think that should happen when you're raising a custom flag.

Comment: Well I did suggest that it should save the custom text as the edit can still invalidate a custom flag and when that happens wouldn't it be better not to spend moderator time on it?

Comment: If you typed faster this wouldn't happen...

Comment: @Machavity There's only so much one can do on a keyboard like the one I have .. :p

Comment: While SE saving this input might be a nice idea, personally, I solve this by using a browser extension that saves that sort of data and allows you to recover it, should it be lost, for whatever reason (page transition, browser crash, system crash, etc.). For Firefox, I use [Textarea Cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/). Given that it's now a WebExtension, there's every reason to expect that something similar exists for Chrome.